# Using refs outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I have a `ImageListComponent` that contains an array of `<ReactSwipe>` elements. Each element have a unique id using `ref={rid}` and is slideable with two slides. The `ImageListComponent` is being used in another component called `<CarFromImage>` that includes methods to add and delete images to `<ImageListComponent>`.

The issue I am having is that inside the `<ImageListComponent>` I am able to programatically swipe an element with the method `this.refs[rid].swipe.prev()` but this is not possible if I want to use this method and reference to the spesific element in `<CarFromImage>`.

Some code in `ImageListComponent.jsx`:

```
             this.props.images.map(function(image, i){

                var rid = "ReactSwipe" + i; 

                return (<ReactSwipe ref={rid} key={i}>
                        <div>
                            <div>Something<div/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div style={styles.deleteIcon} onClick={this.props.deleteImage.bind(this, image, rid)}/>
                        </div>
                    </ReactSwipe>)
              }
```

Some code in `CarFromImage.jsx`:

```
    render: function () {
         return <ImageListComponent carImages={this.state.car.images} addImage={this.addImage} deleteImage={this.deleteImage}/>
```

And the method as I want to use it in `CarFromImage.jsx`:

```
    deleteImage: function(selectedImage, rid){
        this.getFlux().actions.car.deleteImageFromCar(selectedImage);        
        this.refs[rid].swipe.prev();
    }
```

Have anyone used a `ref` outside its component before and know how I can attack this issue or do have some other suggestion? If nothing else I could just throw everything inside one big .jsx-file, but I would like to be able to split my project into smaller components. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You say ImageListComponent contains an array of <ReactSwipe> elements, but your example code does not.

Comment: I'm sorry. Edited the example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assign a ref to your parent node.

Like:

```
render: function () {
     return <ImageListComponent carImages={this.state.car.images} addImage={this.addImage} deleteImage={this.deleteImage} ref="parent" />
}
```

Can you not get the child refs like:

```
deleteImage: function(selectedImage, rid){
    this.getFlux().actions.car.deleteImageFromCar(selectedImage);        
    this.refs.parent.refs[rid].swipe.prev();
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/yixujofixi/1/edit?js,output